# Scan trough .txt file with multiple values on one line. Find right Value

Tags: java, android

I got a .txt file wich i load into a string with Buffered string reader. The data in the String is in this format.

```
20 000  5 000
50 000  6 000
60 000  7 000
80 000  8 000
90 000  9 000
```

I need to go trough these numbers and find the right one. I have a int variable with a number. Lets say the int variable is "24000". Then the right answer from the list would be 20 000. As this is the closest match. I Then need to extract the number after 20 000 (5 000) and write it to a separate int. I cannot change the format of the numbers, because there are like a million of them formated in a .txt file like this.

Summary : UserNumber -> Find closest match from the left side -> Store right side number to an int.
Any ideas on how i can manage this?

Comment: Are values in file always sorted?

Comment: what are the separator at `50 000(this)6 000` is it 2 spaces or 1 tab?

Comment: If we look at the first line its : 20 (one space) 000 (two spaces) 5(one space) 00.

So between 20 000 its one space. And between numbers its 2 spaces.

The values in the files are always going form low -> high.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of delimiters are always constant and list is always sorted, you can use a String.split() which will return a String[] of length 5. The [0] and [1] values when parsed into an Integer would help you in comparing the numbers and find the closest match. The [3] and [4] values would you give you the desired output.

I have written two methods. Once you read the line, pass the string to these methods accordingly

```
//to get the first part of the string as number
private static int checkedVal(String readString) {
    String[] splitString = readString.split(" ");
    return Integer.parseInt(splitString[0] + splitString[1]);
}
//to get the last part of the string as number
private static int correspondingVal(String readString) {
    String[] splitString = readString.split(" ");
    return Integer.parseInt(splitString[3] + splitString[4]);
}
```

The issue here would be the wrong line/delimiter patterns causing a defective program. But if you are sure that wont happen, voila!

Comment: I', sure this would work. Would you mind writing an example? Its so much easier to understand it fully then. I'm considering to rewrite it to 20000=5000 instead, but still I would have to split the array twice since there is whitespace between the lines. So if i split on "=" the right side number would be generated with the left side number on the line below.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the numbers from each line:

```
String[] parts = null;
Long first = null;
Long second = null;

// loop begins
parts = line.split("\\s{1,2}");
first = Long.parseLong(parts[0] + parts[1]);
second = Long.parseLong(parts[2] + parts[3]);

// logic

// loop ends
```

Note that there is single space between the sets of parentheses.